# Shopping cart using OO javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to create a simple shopping cart using javascript and prototypes.

Just a simple console app.

I want to call `myBasket.prototype.addItems` to add items in the `inventory[]` and similarly I would want to call `myBasket.prototype.addQuantity` and `myBasket.prototype.totalAmount` to increase the quantity of an item and sum the total amount respectively.

Where I am stuck is how do I call `myBasket.prototype.addItems` to do the needful? This is where I am stuck.

```
var inventory =
[
    { name: "apples", price: 19.95, quantity: 50 },
    { name: "oranges", price: 20.99, quantity: 40 },
    { name: "pineapples", price: 40.00, quantity: 60 },
    { name: "lemons", price: 10.12, quantity: 100 }
]

function myBasket(name, price, quantity){
   this.name = name;
   this.price = price,
   this.quantity = quantity;
   items.push(this);
}

myBasket.prototype.addItems = function(){
    console.log('items added to cart')
}

myBasket.prototype.addQuantity = function(){
    console.log('item quantity added to cart')
}

myBasket.prototype.totalAmount = function(){
    console.log('Total amount is');
    var total = this.price * this.quantity;
}

// newItem.prototype = Object.create(myBasket.prototype);

var newItem = [];
newItem = new myBasket({name:'milk', price:80,quantity: 2});
newItem.push(this.items);
console.log('new item(s) added', items);

var checkoutAmount = new myBasket();
console.log('checkout amount');
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Because "is this correct" is quite ambiguous. I would certainly NOT go with that approach but mainly because in real world applications things are vastly more complex. However, for our purposes - "a simple console app" it seems quite appropriate. But then what exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: my apologies. let me edit my query.

Comment: @VLAZ I have updated the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since you are new to OOP, think it this way. Every thing is an object.
So in your case, you should have `class Item` and `class Basket` you should also have a way to add and remove items from your basket.

See the code snippet bellow

```js
class Item{
  constructor(name,price,quantity) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
  }
}

class Basket {
  constructor() {
    this.items = []
  }
  
  addItem(item){
    this.items.push(item)
  }
}

let items = [
  new Item("apples",40,20),
  new Item("lemons",32,38),
  new Item("mangos",44,67),
  new Item("pineapples",32,88)
]

let basket = new Basket()

let market = document.getElementById("market")
let s = items.map((item,id)=>"<button onClick=addItem("+id+")>Add "+item.name+"</button>").join("")
market.innerHTML = s

function addItem(id) {
  basket.addItem(items[id])
  showBasket()
}

function showBasket() {
  let cart = document.getElementById("items")
  let s = basket.items.map((item,id)=>"<span style='margin: 5px'>"+item.name+"</span>").join("")
  cart.innerHTML = s
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Basket</legend>
<div id="items"></div>
</fieldset>
<div id="market"></div>
```

Hope that answers your question

Since the question was edited and added to use prototypes, I am going to once more produce an elaboration using function prototypes

```js
function Item(name,price,quantity) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  this.quantity = quantity;
}

function Basket() {
  this.items = []
}

Basket.prototype.addItem = function(item) {
  this.items.push(item);
}

    let items = [
      new Item("apples",40,20),
      new Item("lemons",32,38),
      new Item("mangos",44,67),
      new Item("pineapples",32,88)
    ]

    let basket = new Basket()

    let market = document.getElementById("market")
    let s = items.map((item,id)=>"<button onClick=addItem("+id+")>Add "+item.name+"</button>").join("")
    market.innerHTML = s

    function addItem(id) {
      basket.addItem(items[id])
      showBasket()
    }

    function showBasket() {
      let cart = document.getElementById("items")
      let s = basket.items.map((item,id)=>"<span style='margin: 5px'>"+item.name+"</span>").join("")
      cart.innerHTML = s
    }
```

```html
<fieldset>
<legend>Basket</legend>
<div id=items></div>
</fieldset>
<div id=market></div>
```

Comment: hey, I just have seen your example copied in some photocopies someone gave me to learn Javascript :D ... would it be too much asking if you could write also (you can do it in PM if you prefer), the methods to add items to the basket, calculate the total price of that basket, and detract that amount from the ``ìtems```array?  it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To add items to an array, use `push()`:

```
function myBasket(name, price, quantity){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price,
    this.quantity = quantity;
    items.push(this);
}
```

Comment: It seems weird that `items` isn’t a property of `this`…

Comment: Weird with my answer, or weird with the OP's code layout @deceze?

Comment: Either. If you’re going to suggest a solution, it should be a solution that makes sense as OO code, not just in the context of the OPs insufficient attempt.

Comment: OK sorry @deceze.

Comment: @JackBashford I have updated the description.